# click on element with specified data

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).on('click', $('[data-what="abc"]'), function() {
console.log('323');
$(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.title{
background:gold;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title' data-what='abc'>title</div>
```

console.log - works.

element.hide - doesn't work

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `this` is the element the event was bound to: `document`. You're not trying to hide the whole document.

Try

```
$(document).on('click', $('[data-what="abc"]'), function(event) {
    console.log('323');
    $(event.target).hide();
});
```

Comment: it works. thanks. Can I get `var a = event.target;  a.hide();`

Comment: @puerto `.hide()` is not part of the DOM API. It's been a while since I worked with jQuery, but I think `event.target` returns a bare DOM node, _not_ a jQuery-wrapped DOM node. If you want the sugar of `.hide()`, you need to wrap the node in jQuery to invoke it.